# Find all items from list which have unique values (non-duplicate only) in other

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists with data as following examples

```
var listA = new[]{ "A", "B", "C", "D", "B", "E", "C", "F", "G"};
var listB = new[]{ "A", "B", "C", "E" };
```

listA can have duplicate values.

I need to find all items from listB which have unique values (non-duplicate only) in listA with LINQ or C#.

the expected result listC  should be like

```
listC = {A, E};
```

I am using the following code

```
   var list = listA.GroupBy(x => x).All(g => g.Count() == 1);
   var listC = list.Except(listB).ToList();
```

Comment: This isn't a code writing service I'm afraid. Have you tried anything? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I give you the documentation to the needed functions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-5.0
and 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-5.0

Comment: @DavidG the dupe doesn´t really match I suppose. This question isn´t about finding dupes, but about finding those elements that don´t have dupes.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yeah, you're right. But the answer is a combo of two things, duplicates and intersection, so added some more links to the list.

Answer (score 0):

- You find elements which are not duplicate in their own set for each set.
- Then, take intersection with the other set.

You can make use of `contains()` method since they are of type `string`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var listA = new[]{ "A", "B", "C", "D", "B", "E", "C", "F", "G"};
var listB = new[]{ "A", "B", "C", "E" };
var listC = listB.Where(x=>listA.Where(y=>y==x).Count() == 1);        
foreach(var item in listC) Console.WriteLine(item);
```

The Simplest most naive solution I could think of. Smells like homework though.

Comment: If it smells like homework, why add an answer?

Comment: Why did you feel the need to comment on everything here?

Comment: Because I care about the quality of the content posted here.

Comment: Then you can see why adding unnecessary comments directly conflicts with your argument.

Comment: If my comments are unnecessary, what does that say about your answer?

Comment: A question was asked, an answer was given. Now my lunch break is over, and now it's back to work.